# How I can make same results on cx_Oracle and Sql * Plus?

Tags: python, cx-oracle

It's - for sqlplus - commands:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec where.my_package.ger_result('something');
something=1823655138
```

And it's - for cx_Oracle:

```
>>> c.callproc('where.my_package.ger_result', ('something',))
['something']
```

As You can see - the results are different.
I have no idea, how to fix it. :[

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import cx_Oracle

dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('my_ip_address_server_next_port', 0000, 'sid')
db = cx_Oracle.connect('user', 'password', dsn_tns)
curs = db.cursor()
curs.callproc("dbms_output.enable")

curs.callproc('where.my_package.ger_result', ['something',])

statusVar = curs.var(cx_Oracle.NUMBER)
lineVar = curs.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
while True:
  curs.callproc("dbms_output.get_line", (lineVar, statusVar))
  if statusVar.getvalue() != 0:
    break
  print lineVar.getvalue()
```

Comment: Is this Python code what you've used to solve your problem, or is it extra information you're providing to help others solve your problem?  If the latter, please edit your question to add this information instead.

Comment: This is a my decision of this problem.. but I can't yet (just after 24 hours) make it as "answer".

Comment: Thanks for clearing up my query.  The reason I asked was that some people who haven't used SO much tend to add extra information to a question they've asked by adding an answer, when they should be editing their question.  I couldn't be entirely sure you hadn't done this, as it wasn't immediately clear to me that this was the solution to your problem, so I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't reproduce this one.

I don't have your PL/SQL package, so I used the following stored procedure instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_do_somet (
    p_param     IN VARCHAR2
) AS
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line(p_param || '=1823655138');
END;
/
```

I got the same output, `something=1823655138`, from SQL*Plus and from using the Python script in your answer.

If you're getting different results using SQL*Plus and cx_Oracle, then either your stored procedure is doing something very funny (I don't know what could cause it to do this), or your SQL*Plus session and Python script are not connecting to the same database and/or schema.

Comment: Thanks 4your answer. And I answered below, how We are can get a result yet.